# Example of powershell which will retrieve usage of CPU,MEMORY,HARDDISK and NETWORK

Tags: powershell, wmi

I tried to retrieve information about HARDDISK and NETWORK using c++ code.
I made this using queries(Eg: Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk ) which will give these information.
I never done any powershell code before.so can you help me to get these information using powershell or can you give some more example to help me do this.

Thanks,
Deepesh C.P

Answer (score 0):

You can perform WMI Queries using the [`Get-WmiObject`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx) cmdlet in PowerShell.